# Find min and max of $A = \sqrt{x-2} + 2\sqrt{x+1} + 2019 -x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, alternative-proof, maxima-minima

> Find minimum and maximum of $$A = \sqrt{x-2} +  2\sqrt{x+1} + 2019 -x$$

How to solve this problem without using derivatives?

---

[Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg)'s edit:

Because with a derivative it's not so easy:
$$A'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}-1=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-2}}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}-\frac{1}{2}=$$
$$=\frac{1-\sqrt{x-2}}{2\sqrt{x-2}}+\frac{2-\sqrt{x+1}}{2\sqrt{x+2}}=$$
$$=(3-x)\left(\frac{1}{2(1+\sqrt{x-2})\sqrt{x-2}}+\frac{1}{2(2+\sqrt{x+1})\sqrt{x+2}}\right),$$
which gives $x_{max}=3.$

Comment: Tthe limit is minus infinity when $x\to\infty$. Thus, there is no minimum.

Comment: @ Wlod AA So what is the maximum value of $A$?

Comment: Ooops, I've misread the Q. :)

Comment: Derivatives are really the best way to go in maximization and minimization problems

Comment: Dear @Zarrax I really don't agree with you! See please my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Sometimes, with some difficulty/cleverness you can find elementary solutions to such problems, but differentiation is a systematic approach that will work on a large range of problems, and won't require any tricks specific to a given problem.

Comment: @Zarrax The topic starter knows this. By using derivatives, this problem is obvious for him. He looked for a way without using derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sqrt{x-2}+2\sqrt{x+1}-x+2019=\sqrt{x-2}+4\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{4}}-x+2019\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt{(1+4)\left(x-2+4\cdot\frac{x+1}{4}\right)}-x+2019=\sqrt{5(2x-1)}-x+2019\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{5+2x-1}{2}-x+2019=2021.$$
The equality occurs for $x=3,$ which says that we got a maximal value.

The minimum does not exist. Try $x\rightarrow+\infty.$

Comment: A very good solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Success You are welcome!

Comment: Can down-voter explain us why did you do it?

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x-2} +  2\sqrt{x+1} + 2019 -x$ then

$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x - 2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} - 1
$$

Equating this to zero for real $x$, we get $x = 3$. The second derivative is negative hence the global maximum is $f(3) = 2021.$

Comment: If not using the derivative of the function, how is this problem solved?

Comment: @Success Well in that case, you should first mention in your question that you want to maximum without using derivative

Comment: @Nilotpal Kanti Sinha,  one tag is "algebra-pre-calculus". So, the banning of derivatives seems clear enough.

Comment: It's easier to see and say that the first derivative is decreasing for $\,x>2.\ $ To look at the 2nd derivative would be a pain in the neck.

Comment: @BernardMassé That's OK but if you want something specific, mentioning it in the question makes it less likely to be over-sighted

Answer (score 2):

$$ \forall_{y\ge -1}\quad\sqrt{1+y}\ \le\ 1+\frac y2 $$

hence

$$ \forall_{x\ge 2}\quad\sqrt{x-2}\ =\ \sqrt{1+(x-3)}\ \le\ 1 +\frac{x-3}2 $$
and
$$ \forall_{x\ge -1}\quad\sqrt{x+1}\ =\ 2\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{x-3}4}\ \le
           \ 2+\frac{x-3}4 $$
hence
$$ \forall_{x\ge 2}\quad\sqrt{x-2}\ +\ 2\cdot\sqrt{x+1}\ \le\ 2+x $$
i.e.
$$ \forall_{x\ge 2}\quad\sqrt{x-2}\ +\ 2\cdot\sqrt{x+1}\ -\ x\ \le\ 2 $$

where the equality holds only for $\ x=3.\ $ Thus A (see the ***OP Question***) attains its maximum $A=2021$ at $x=3$.   ***Great!***

Comment: Nice; you could say $\forall y\color{red}\ge-1$ and $\forall x\color{red}\ge2$, right?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, right! Thank you -- I'll implement your improvement.